# sender mail with php

Tags: php, email

I use this code to send mail. But it stopped working when I added the **$headers** and lines to **$body**. Can anyone support me in finding the error or errors?

I would appreciate the support.

```
<?PHP

// Email Address
$youremail = 'correo@correo.com';
$memberemail = $_POST['email'];

// Register Form
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

    // Detect & Prevent Header Injections
    $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
        if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
            exit;
        }
    }

    // Email Format
    $body  =    "Hola! $_POST[name]. Gracias por solicitar tu inscripción. \n";
    $body .=    "Analizaremos tú solicitud y en caso de resultar positiva recibirás un correo de confirmación en las próximas 24 horas. \n\n";
    $body .=    "Tus datos de solicitud son: \r\n"
    $body .=    "============================ \r\n";
    $body .=    "Nombre:  $_POST[name] \n";
    $body .=    "eMail:  $_POST[email] \n";
    $body .=    "Empresa:  $_POST[telephone] \n";
    $body .=    "Sector:  $_POST[ticket] \n\n";
    $body .=    "Atentamente, \n";
    $body .=    "Staff \n\n";
    $body .=    "NOTA: Para culaquier duda sobre tu proceso de inscripción te recomendamos leer las preguntas frecuentes en el sito web del evento http://www.evento.com";

    //Send email

    $headers = "From: Staff <contacto@evento.com>" . "\r\n" . "Bcc: admin@evento.com" . "\r\n";

    mail( "To:" . $memberemail , "Nuevo registro", $body, "From:" . $headers);

}

// Subscribe Form
if( isset($_POST['subscriber']) && filter_var($_POST['subscriber'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
    $data = $_POST['subscriber'] . ";" . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('subscribers.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('Ouch! Al parecer hay un error.');
    }
} else {
    die('No se pueden enviar los datos.');
}

?>
```

Comment: why not just use http://www.tectite.com/formmailpage.php

Comment: Procura primero revisar la documentación oficial http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php, pero procura buscar otras opciones (librerías u otros)... tu respuesta ya la dio @Fred -ii-

Comment: If you already saw my answer and it did not work, I noticed another problem when testing your code in order to make sure if it worked or not (which it did work), there was a missing semi-colon. Please reload my answer to see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$body, "From:" . $headers)` to `$body, $headers)`

You already have the `From:` in:

```
$headers = "From: Staff <contacto@evento.com>"...
```

Plus as noted in comments, change and remove the `"To:" .`

```
mail( "To:" . $memberemail , "Nuevo registro", $body, "From:" . $headers);
```

to

```
mail($memberemail, "Nuevo registro", $body, $headers);
```

Mail automatically sets the first parameter as the recipient `To:`

However, you may have wanted to use `$youremail` as the first parameter and `$memberemail` as the `From:`, because mail will be sent to the person who sent the Email, but I will let you decide on that.

Consult the manual:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php**

---

**Edit:**

There is a missing semi-colon in the following line (*which I overlooked*) before testing your code:

```
body .=    "Tus datos de solicitud son: \r\n"
                                             ^ missing semi-colon
```

add it

```
body .=    "Tus datos de solicitud son: \r\n";
```

If error reporting was set, you would have seen the following parse/syntax error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$body' (T_VARIABLE) in /server/path/file.php on line (number)

When PHP signals a parse error on a line number, it is usually on a line "before" that, and not the actual line number itself.

- If you see a parse error on line 22, then the fault will most likely be on line 21, and not 22.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Additionally, remove "To:" from the recipient parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the following:

1. Set SPF record on evento.com domain to allow this ip or subnet to use this From address. You can use a tool like this: http://www.spfwizard.net/
2. Add PTR record on event.com domain pointing to the IP of the sending host
3. Remove the whole body and try to add line-by-line (making sure content-based spam filters are not in effect)
4. Watch your mail log and see whether it's sent out by MTA and your smarthost response code.

And you should specify what exactly you mean by "stopped working": was it sent out from the server? Did it land into junk box? Was it rejected by your smarthost?